# Illegal offset type - в чем проблема?

Tags: php

Добрый день. Формирую JS таким выражением:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($configNames)); $i++) {
echo "$('#".$configNames[$i]."').text('".$config[$configNames[$i]]."');";}
```

В ответ получаю ругательства на это выражение вида "Illegal offset type", но сам скрипт при этом выполняется как надо. Какой расово-верный вариант применить на замену, дабы избежать ругательств?

Всем спасибо за ответы. Вариант с использованием дополнительной переменной убрал ругательства, но остановился на варианте с циклом foreach, т.к., видимо, он более каноничен.

Comment: Проверьте, что в ваших массивах  `var_dump($configNames, $config)`. Думаю, должно прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что внутри элементов перебираемого массива есть кавычки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Счевидно, что массив `$config` - вложенный, и его элементами могут быть как скаляры, так и другие массивы.
Как следствие, видимо, $configNames - тоже имеет иерархическую структуру, хотя я бы этого не делал.

```
foreach ($configNames as $name)
{
    if (!is_array($name))
    {
        echo "$('#$name').text('$config[$name]');";
    }
}
```

Плюс я в принципе не понимаю, зачем здесь отдельный массив `$configNames`.
Если он не служит для фильтрации определенных элементов, а в точности содержит ключи массива `$config`, то он в принципе не нужен:

```
foreach ($config as $name => $value)
{
    if (is_scalar($value))
    {
        echo "$('#$name').text('$value');";
    }
}
```

но оба этих кода **пропустят** вложенные массивы. Если их тоже надо передать в JS, то нужна будет рекурсивная функция

Answer (score 2):

Дополняя остальные ответы.

Первое, что не стоит делать - это формировать javascript динамически. **Вы не видите конечного результата**, ошибку допустить проще простого. Передавайте данные в виде JSON-строки тем или иным способом (`window.pageData = <?php echo json_encoode($data); ?>` или через data-атрибуты).

Второе - у вас сложная и неочевидная структура данных, из-за которой и происходят эти ошибки. Вы не можете заглянуть внутрь происходящего в коде без отладчика, и это сильно затрудняет дебаг.

Answer (score 0):

вот пример https://saitsozdanie.ru/forum/index.php?topic=9339.0 обычно ключ просто неправильный

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от ответов-ссылок, желательно добавить часть кода оттуда в свой ответ

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($configNames)); $i++) {
    $name = $configNames[$i];
    echo "$('#".$name."').text('".$config[$name]."');";
}
```

К тому же, думаю, в данном случае нагляднее будет использовать цикл `foreach`.